# C++ program: map in which key is name and three other parameters

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, iterator

I have a program in C++ that contains the code below. I want to know whether accessing members of the `timeval` struct from the iterator like this:

```
time_iter->second.tv_sec
```

is correct or not.

```
 static std::map<std::string,struct timeval> name_time_map;
 std::map<std::string,struct timeval>::iterator time_iter;

 time_iter = name_time_map.find(name);

 if (time_iter == name_time_map.end()) {
   gettimeofday(&tvPrev, NULL); 
   name_time_map[name]=tvPrev;
 }
 else {
   print("what inserted values have");
   gettimeofday(&tvCurrent, NULL);
   diff = 
     (tvCurrent.tv_usec + 1000000 * tvCurrent.tv_sec) - 
     (time_iter->second.tv_usec + 1000000 * time_iter->second.tv_sec);

   tvDiff.tv_sec = diff / 1000000;
   tvDiff.tv_usec = diff % 1000000; // micro seconds
 }
```

My concern is that accessing the inserted value using `time_iter->second.tv_sec` may not be allowed given that `second` points to a predefined structure `struct timeval`.

Comment: Have you tested it? Did it work?

Comment: No i haven't tested it. I wanted to present my contest over here to understand more. Or do we have any other way to access a predefined structure member using an iterator.

Comment: Testing is what programming is all about though... If you ask here before testing always, you'll have a LOT of unnecessarily asked questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. For example, running the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   struct MyStruct
   {
      int someValue;
   };
   map<string, struct MyStruct> exampleMap;
   MyStruct exampleStruct;
   exampleStruct.someValue = 5;
   exampleMap["exampleKey"] = exampleStruct;
   map<string, struct MyStruct>::iterator exampleIterator = exampleMap.find("exampleKey");
   cout << exampleIterator->second.someValue;
}
```

Results in this output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

From the outset it *looks* OK (disregarding the rather intimidating indentation practices). Having said this, the truth is in the testing.

Comment: That was my impression also, although it's hard to comment on the overall code as it relies on other code we can't see. But the principle of what he's asking seems fine.